# Equivalent in Coldfusion for JavaScript's call() and apply() functions

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I need to achieve similar functionality to JavaScript's call() or apply() functions in Coldfusion 8. I need a way to dynamically bind my 'this' context for the function being called. Short of manually passing in the context inside the argument list, is there any other way to do this? Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time searching for clues on Google because I can't seem to search the keyword 'this'.

```
<!--- component A --->
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset this.value = "My name is A">
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="setDelegate">
        <cfargument name="delegate">

        <cfset this.delegate = delegate>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="runDelegate">
        <cfoutput>#this.delegate()#</cfoutput>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<!--- component B --->
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset this.value = "Hello, I am B">
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="call">
        <cfoutput>#this.value#</cfoutput>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<!--- main cfm --->
<cfset mrA = createObject('component', 'A').init()>
<cfset mrB = createObject('component', 'B').init()>

<cfset mrA.setDelegate(mrB.call)>

<!--- I want to return "Hello, I am B", --->
<!--- but it's going to output "My name is A" in this case --->
<cfoutput>#mrA.runDelegate()#</cfoutput>
```

In the example above, the 'this' context belongs to A, but I want to bind the context to B to make use of B's properties.

This is easy to do in JavaScript by simply passing in mrB into the call() function:
mrA.runDelegate.call(mrB); which will set the 'this' context to mrB instead of mrA.

Comment: forgive me, but i'm not following your question. maybe it would help if you gave an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've added some example code to clarify what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to dynamically call a method from within a given component you probably need to do something like

```
<cfinvoke component="#this#" method="#methodToCall#">
   <cfinvokeargument name="#prop#" value="#someValue#" />
</cfinvoke>
```

That would use the whole of "this" and call the method in the component, so your context should be intact.

If you are just calling a method in a component in the standard way then "this" is available without doing anything special.

To give you a better solution we'd need to know what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually think this is possible because this scope is the public scope of a CFC instance, replacing the context of this is no simple matter. However, as @rip747 suggested if you were a bit clearer on what you are after maybe there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I think I've figured it out. I should also be passing in the context along with the delegate to call. I suddenly realized I was missing an argument when I was thinking of how I did it in JavaScript.

```
<!--- Component A --->
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="init"> 
        <cfset this.value = "My name is A">
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="setDelegate">
        <cfargument name="delegate">
        <cfargument name="context">

        <cfset this.delegate = delegate>
        <cfset this.context = context>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="runDelegate">
        <cfoutput>#this.delegate()#</cfoutput>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<!--- component B --->
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="init">
        <cfset this.value = "Hello, I am B">
        <cfreturn this>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="call">
        <cfoutput>#this.value#</cfoutput>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<!--- main cfm --->
<cfset mrA = createObject('component', 'A').init()>
<cfset mrB = createObject('component', 'B').init()>

<cfset mrA.setDelegate("call", mrB)>

<cfoutput>
    <cfinvoke component="#mrA.context#" method="#mrA.delegate#"></cfinvoke>
</cfoutput>
```